# php utf8_decode doesn't recognize square root from $_GET

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8, utf8-decode

When i send this perfect square character:

```
25²
```

And retrieve it in another page using utf8_decode i get (as expected):

```
25²
```

Now i want to do the same thing with square roots. When i send this square root:

```
√225
```

And retrieve (_$GET) it using utf8_decode as before i get:

```
?255
```

Note: i would prefer a method that will solve this when i retrieve the value (like âˆš225) and not a method that will force me to change the initial representation of it.

Edit: I thought i was using mysql but i'm not. sorry for misleading. this is the script i use to retrieve the value:

```
if (isset($_GET['json'])){  
  $json = urldecode($_GET['json']);
  $roots = json_decode($json, true);
  $arrList = utf8_decode(implode(",,,", $roots['nameList']));
  print_r($arrList)
}
```

Comment: How do you try to get the value from the database? Show your query ..

Comment: How come phpMyAdmin is seeing it as CP1252 instead of UTF-8?

Comment: phpMyAdmin has a lot of mysteries :)

Comment: Sure, but I don't remember it being quite *this* broken...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `utf8_decode` function converts a string from UTF-8 to latin1. The square root symbol is not available in latin1, so `utf8_decode` substitutes it with a question mark. This doesn't happen with ² because it does exist in latin1, in position 0xB2. (You can check which characters are available in the page of [latin1 in Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1))

A possible solution is removing the call to `utf8_decode` and leave the text as UTF-8, but then you have to make sure the rest of your code can handle UTF-8.

Answer (score 0):

The square root character is not included in ISO-8859-1. So it **cannot** be converted, which results in a question mark. If you want to use special characters like that, better stick with UTF-8